# Why does java.lang.Exception not allow setting message outside constructor?

Tags: java, exception

Why does [`java.lang.Exception`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) not provide a setter for the message and allow setting it only via the constructor (e.g. `super(_msg)`)?

For example:

```
public BadParameterException(QueryParameter _param, String _valStr) {

    this.param = _param;
    this.valAsStr = _valStr;
}

public BadParameterException(QueryParameter _param, String _valStr, String _msg) {

    this(_param, _valStr);
    /* This is not possible */ super.setMessage(_msg);
}
```

instead, I have to do this:

```
public BadParameterException(QueryParameter _param, String _valStr, String _msg) {

    super(_msg);
    this.param = _param;
    this.valAsStr = _valStr;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because an Exception is a snapshot of a situation. It's not supposed to change it's state.

Since the message can only be set through the constructor, it's basically `final` and cannot be changed afterwards. That's how it was designed.